# How do I copy an Item via DyanmoDB.streams to another table?

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

When I delete an item on tableX, I would like that item to be copied exactly to tableY.

Here is my code so far:

```
var dynamodb = require("aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb");
var documentClient = new dynamodb.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  for (const streamedItem of event.Records) {
    if (streamedItem.eventName === "REMOVE") {
      var params = {
        TableName: "tableY"
        Item: streamedItem.dynamodb.OldImage,
      };

      documentClient.put(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(data);
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what error you are seeing, but from what it seems you are not awaiting the request to DynamoDB meaning the Lambda will end before processing all of the items.

DynamoDB `put` API returns a `Promise` in JS, adding await to this will wait for the processing to complete.

```
await client.put({
    TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
    Item: item
}).promise().then(res => {
    console.log(res)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

As you are iterating through a number of items calling `put` you may also add the promises to an array and outside of the loop call `promise.all(myproises)`  Details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Also note that streams delivers the item in DynamoDB JSON and you are using Document Client which expected Native JSON which would cause a mismatch with your item. If you wish to continue with Document Client then you should `unmarshall` the payload: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/Converter.html#unmarshall-property

Furthermore, if your Lambda function is only being used to action items which were deleted i.e: `REMOVE` then you can make use of [Lambda Event Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html) to reduce your Lambda invocations and costs.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: "2012-08-10" });

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  for (const streamedItem of event.Records) {
    if (streamedItem.eventName === "REMOVE") {
      var params = {
        TableName: "tableY",
        Item: streamedItem.dynamodb.OldImage,
      };

      try {
        await dynamodb.putItem(params).promise();
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  }
};
```